# Locating specific datapoints in R and merging matrices

Tags: r, lookup

I have two datasets and i need to merge specific points from these two datasets in a third matrix which i will create.
I am trying to create a matrix with stock returns for all the companies in my dataset.
My dataset of the companies (referencedata) looks like this:

```
Company PERNMO    earlengage
A        45643    6/7/2011
B        86743    9/12/2012
C        75423    3/4/2011
D        95345    2/11/2011
......
```

My dataset of the stock returns (datastock) looks like this:

```
PERNMO    date      returns
11456     1/3/2011   3.4%
11456     1/4/2011   5.4%
11456     1/5/2011   0.5%
11456     1/6/2011   1.2%
11456     1/7/2011   0.7%
......
```

I need to use the `PERMNO` code in `referencedata` as an identifier to locate the company i am looking for in `datastock`. At the same time, i need to use `earlengage` in `referencedata` as an identifier to find the same date in `datastock` and then select the 250 `returns` datapoints prior to that day in `datastock`.
I want to put all these 250 datapoints for each stock in one matrix (250 rows for the `returns` & `n` columns relating to the number of stocks).

I am struggling to replicate the equivalent of the vlookup function in Excel. The output matrix would look like this:

PERNMO       date    returns

```
45643     1/3/2011   3.4%
45643     1/4/2011   5.4%
45643     1/5/2011   0.5%
```

......

```
45643     6/7/2011   1.2%

       (this is the earlengage date)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `merge` followed by some reshaping/splitting? Please provide more representative input data (you don't need 250 data points, 3 are sufficient) and show exactly the desired output.

Comment: @Roland i added how the output matrix would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you are trying to solve two problems in one shot. The first one is merging, and the other is taking the last 250 data points and converting it into a matrix. I'd approach this problem in the simplest way possible by going through the rows one by one rather than trying to solve it using one function

```
# Sorting so that we can take the bottom 250 rows to find the latest data
datastock = datastock[order(datastock$date),]

dataMatrix = NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(referencedata))
{
   single_stock_data = subset(datastock, PERNMO == referencedata$PERNMO[i] &  
                                         date < referencedata$PERNMO[i])

   dataMatrix = cbind(dataMatrix, tail(single_stock_data$returns, 251)[1:250]
}
```

I haven't tested the code but this should work.

Comment: Thanks @Azrael , this is what i was looking for. I am however now struggling to select the 250 datapoints prior to the "earlengage" date. I used the tail function and that spits out the last 250 datapoints not the 250 points prior to "earlengage". Any ideas on how i could do that?

Comment: You might have figured this out already, but here goes -    tail(single_stock_data$returns, 251)[1:250]

Comment: I keep getting: Error in Ops.factor(single_stock_data$date[j], dummydate) : level sets of factors are different



for (i in 1:nrow(referencedata)) {
 single_stock_data = subset(datastock,pernmo==referencedata$pernmo[i])
 dummydate = referencedata$earlengage[i]
  if (nrow(single_stock_data)>0) {
      for (j in 1:nrow(single_stock_data)) {
        if (single_stock_data$date[j] == dummydate) {
         single_stock_data = tail(single_stock_data$returns, j)[1:250]
          datamatrix = cbind(datamatrix, single_stock_data$returns)
          single_stock_data <- NULL
}
}
}
}

Comment: I have updated the code. Try it now? I don't think you need to use the two for loops and conditionals in your case.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks @Azrael !